# Posting messages after DestroyWindow

Tags: message, win32gui

In win32, what happens if a message is posted to a window handle after its been destroyed?

It's been said that DestroyWindow flushes the message queue? Will it flush only the messages posted to that window? It should be so right? If it flushes the entire message queue then if multiple windows are created by that thread, that would be problem right?

consider multiple windows are created with single message loop,

If I destroy a winow and post a message to that window handle what will happen? Will it be dispatched and crash?

Can someone explain me in-depth of Message queue?

Comment: I think `SendMessage()` and `PostMessage()` will return 0 and if you check the last error using `GetLastError()` you will get a value of 1400 - `ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE`.

Comment: Already existing messages? Will it flush the messages specific to the window or all?